# Room Database Issue in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

In Android Room Databse i am getting this Exception

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

Here is My Entity class

```
@Entity(tableName = "tableName")
public class EntityName implements Serializable {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int userId;
```

}

Here is my Dao interface

```
@Dao
interface DaoName {
@get:Query("SELECT * FROM tableName")
val all: ArrayList<EntityName>

@Insert
fun insert(entiname: EntityName?):Long

@Delete
fun delete(entiname: EntityName?)

@Update
fun update(entiname: EntityName?)
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had this issue in Room Database

Use

```
List<EntityName>
```

Instead of

```
ArrayList<EntityName>
```